# Update the value of a field with Odoo 10

Tags: python, odoo

I have a button and I want to update the values ​​of several fields using the create method.
Would you like to help me create this function?
At the moment, when I click on my button, it replaces my record and creates another one with empty values. Why? Thank you
It's not a real wizard !

```
class StudentWizard(models.Model):
    _name = 'student.wizard'

    def _get_default_students(self):
        return self.env['ecole.partner.school'].browse(self.env.context.get('active_ids'))

    student_ids = fields.Many2many('ecole.partner.school', String="Student", default=_get_default_students)
    school_name = fields.Many2one(comodel_name="horanet.school.establishment",
                                string="Etablissement Scolaire",
                                required=True)
    school_year = fields.Many2one(string='Période',
                                ondelete='SET NULL',
                                comodel_name="ecole.partner.school.years",
                                required=True)
    school_level = fields.Many2one(comodel_name="horanet.school.grade",
                                string="Niveau Scolaire",
                                required=True)
    #level = fields.Char('Level')

    api.multi
    def set_student_level(self):
        for record in self:
            if record.student_ids:
                for student in record.student_ids:
                    update_student = self.env['ecole.partner.school']
                    # partner_id = update_student.partner_id
                    # school_year = update_student.school_year
                    # school_name = update_student.school_name
                    # half_pension = update_student.half_pension
                    # nursery = update_student.nursery

                    student.school_year = update_student.school_year
                    student.school_level = update_student.school_level
                    #student.school_name = update_student.school_name

                    vals = {'school_year': student.school_year, 'school_level': student.school_level}
                    res = update_student.create(vals)


                return res
```

My XML :

```
    <record id="student_wizard_view" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">student Marks Views</field>
        <field name="model">student.wizard</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form>
                <group>
                    <field name="student_ids" widget="many2many_list"/>
                    <field name="school_name"/>
                    <field name="school_year"/>
                    <field name="school_level"/>
                </group>
                <footer>
                    <button name="set_student_level" string="Passage au niveau suivant" class="oe_right oe_highlight"
                            type="object"/>
                    <button string="Cancel" class="oe_right" special="cancel"/>
                </footer>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
```

My result :
[My records are empty and erase the field values ​​of the selected record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4Px5.jpg)

My View :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qeww4.png)

Comment: Could you please add more information? What models are involved? Where is the button clicked? Try to explain it in more detail, it will help you, too.

Comment: Do you want to create a new record or update an existing one?

Comment: I want to create a new record by clicking a button from a selected record. I want to update the selected record without erasing it. I want to retrieve the information from the view (selected by the user) and save it in the database

Comment: I changed the announcement of my question to be more specific

Comment: please help me for my code